# Copy node and change attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to duplicate the ComponentGroup node and modify the Id attribute.

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="AnotherGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>  
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I can duplicate the ComponentGroup node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup'>
    <!--the original-->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
     <!--duplicate--> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

But for the life of me I can not figure out how to update the Id of the second ComponentGroup to "AnotherGroup".

If I try to add "mode" like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup'>
    <!--the original-->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
     <!--duplicate--> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="someMode"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then my output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup>SomeGroup</ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I was hoping that I could then later match using someMode somehow...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This appears to work, but I am bit confused now as to why it doesn't modify the Id of both ComponentGroup and instead only the second one I added using xsl:copy

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup'>
    <!--the original-->
    <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
    <!--duplicate--> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup/@Id'>
    <xsl:attribute name='Id'>AnotherGroup</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT2:**
Ruben suggested the following solution that works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup'>
    <!--the original-->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <!--duplicate--> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">AnotherGroup</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I want to edit so that my desired output is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="AnotherGroup">
      <ComponentRef Id="AnotherCptRefId" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09" />
    </ComponentGroup>  
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

How might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `xsl:attribute` tag to achieve your result like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup'>
    <!--the original-->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <!--duplicate--> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">AnotherGroup</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Fragment>
      <ComponentGroup Id="SomeGroup">
         <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89"/>
         <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09"/>
      </ComponentGroup>
      <ComponentGroup Id="AnotherGroup">
         <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89"/>
         <ComponentRef Id="cmp8ACD64282EEF7EAC19C62C7B2AFACA09"/>
      </ComponentGroup>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. What if I then wanted to edit the Id of the          <ComponentRef Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89"/> in the new new ComponentGroup (with Id="AnotherGroup") (the next thing I am struggling with in this example...)

Comment: How you want to edit it?

Comment: I think you cal add something like this:

Comment: <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup/wix:ComponentRef[./@Id="cmp4CFDF03BB139F024CF278CD5B0CE2D89"]'>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">Modified ID</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:text>Modified Value</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>